# Trying to redirect page using Zend FW.

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to redirect the page if condition is true I dont want to use core php function header() because I am using zend so, I have tried many things but in vain.

Here is my code.

```
  $viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
  $table = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('sitebusiness_business');
  $select = $table->select()->where('owner_id = ?' , $viewer->getIdentity());
  $result = $table->fetchAll($select);
   if(count($result) == 0){
      $url = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble(array('action' => 'package'), 'sitebusiness_general', true); // url is /mysite/businessitems/package
      $this->_redirect($url); //Not Working ---- 
      $this->_helper->redirector($url); //Not Working ---- 
      $this->_redirector->gotoSimple($url); //Not Working ---- 
      $this->_redirector->gotoUrl($url); //Not Working ---- 
   }
```

Everytime I get the message: Fatal error: Call to a member function redirector() [whatever the function name is] on a non-object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following one to redirect in `zf2`

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('routename');
```

Generaly route name is the function name in the controller.

like addEmployeeAction(), editEmployeeAction()...

which is routes defined in `module.config.php`

```
  'zfcadmin' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/admin',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'ZfcAdmin\Controller\AdminController',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
```